# Combination for a group of objects

Tags: combinations

Assuming we have 7 boxes, where each box has a number and a color. The color can have one of two available colors, for example: box1 can either be red or blue, box2 either black or white, box3 either orange or yellow...and so on. so there are 7 boxes and each box has two options, how many combinations can we have? Could you please show me a formula to calculate this and its name.

Edit: 
Each box has its own two unique colors, so if box1 has red and blue, in each combination it will have either red or blue but no other box will have red or blue. 
is it 2 * 2 * 2 * ... * 2 = 2 to the power of 7?

Thanks

Comment: I cannot work it out from the description that you give. It is EITHER Binary words of length $7$ OR signed permutations on $7$ elements. ... What do other folks think ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. is it 2 * 2 * 2 * ... * 2 = 2 to the power of 7?

Comment: actually that's a comment for more specifics.

Comment: it also arguably depends on if all colors are distinct.

Comment: yes each box has its own two unique colors, so if box1 has red and blue, in each combination it will have either red or blue but no other box will have red or blue.

Comment: does the number mean anything other than a label, all of this can be added to the post BTW.

Comment: I just edited it.  the number is just a unique label, so each box is different from the other.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct by the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Comment: Thanks but as far as i understand using the rule of power means 2*7 not 2^7?